# Format a date in VBA using a different language

Tags: vba, ms-access

When I use the Format statement in VBA, I often use Excel to build the format element of the command.  This usual works fine.  However I want to output a date in Italian.  In a spreadsheet the formula "=TEXT(NOW(), "[$-410]d mmmm yyyy")" retuns "12 aprile 2018".  But if I write the following in VBA

MsgBox Format(Now(), "[$-410]d mmmm yyyy")

I get "12 April 2018" and not the Italian version that I was hoping for.  My reason for asking is that I would like to create an Italian date in VBA in Access so don't want to use Excel to do it.

I guess the problem is that the format statement does not like the "[$-410]" element.  Is there something else I can put in the format string to get an Italian date?  Can I change a system setting in the VBA to output Italian dates and change it back again in the macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA only "knows" the local month names. So, you may have to run your own function similar to this for the English names:

```
' Returns the English month name for the passed month number.
' Accepted numbers are 1 to 12. 
' If Abbreviate is True, the returned name is abbreviated.
'
' 2015-11-25. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function MonthNameInvariant( _
    ByVal Month As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal Abbreviate As Boolean) _
    As String

    Const AbbreviatedLength As Integer = 3

    Dim MonthName( _
        MinMonthValue To _
        MaxMonthValue)      As String
    Dim Name                As String

    ' Non-localized (invariant) month names.
    MonthName(1) = "January"
    MonthName(2) = "February"
    MonthName(3) = "March"
    MonthName(4) = "April"
    MonthName(5) = "May"
    MonthName(6) = "June"
    MonthName(7) = "July"
    MonthName(8) = "August"
    MonthName(9) = "September"
    MonthName(10) = "October"
    MonthName(11) = "November"
    MonthName(12) = "December"

    If Abbreviate = True Then
        Name = Left(MonthName(Month), AbbreviatedLength)
    Else
        Name = MonthName(Month)
    End If

    MonthNameInvariant = Name

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping to avoid this, but did not realise this VBA limitation. I will probably put the months in a table as this means they can be edited later for a different country.

Comment: Good idea. Then add a field with language or country code to the table and filter on that.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a solution to this, it's to use the worksheet function, as that one can be forced to use a specific language. And it is accessible in VBA through Application.WorksheetFunction :

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Date,  "[$-410]d mmmm yyyy")
```

then you can use any language settings ([listed here](https://software-solutions-online.com/excel-custom-formatting-month-languange/) for example)