# Set a date language in MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, outlook, locale

I have a form in Access where I have a textbox which generates an email in Outlook. This email has to populate the date for a specific event. My PC language is French (Canada), so the month displays in French in the email while the rest is in English.

No matter which language the PC is in, I want the date to be in English.
i.e. 'December 19, 2022' or '19 December 2022', instead of '19 décembre 2022'.

Comment: According to [Format a date and time field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-a-date-and-time-field-47fbbdc1-52fa-416a-b8d5-ba24d881b698): *[...] formats for dates and times vary depending on the geographic location specified in the Microsoft Windows Regional and Language Options setting on your computer.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use my function `MonthNameInvariant`:

```vb
' Constants:
    Public Const MaxMonthValue          As Integer = 12
    Public Const MinMonthValue          As Integer = 1


' Returns the English month name for the passed month number.
' Accepted numbers are 1 to 12. Other values will raise an error.
' If Abbreviate is True, the returned name is abbreviated.
'
' 2015-11-25. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function MonthNameInvariant( _
    ByVal Month As Long, _
    Optional ByVal Abbreviate As Boolean) _
    As String
    
    Const AbbreviatedLength As Integer = 3
    
    Dim MonthName( _
        MinMonthValue To _
        MaxMonthValue)      As String
    Dim Name                As String
    
    If Not IsMonth(Month) Then
        Err.Raise DtError.dtInvalidProcedureCallOrArgument
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Non-localized (invariant) month names.
    MonthName(1) = "January"
    MonthName(2) = "February"
    MonthName(3) = "March"
    MonthName(4) = "April"
    MonthName(5) = "May"
    MonthName(6) = "June"
    MonthName(7) = "July"
    MonthName(8) = "August"
    MonthName(9) = "September"
    MonthName(10) = "October"
    MonthName(11) = "November"
    MonthName(12) = "December"
    
    If Abbreviate = True Then
        Name = Left(MonthName(Month), AbbreviatedLength)
    Else
        Name = MonthName(Month)
    End If
    
    MonthNameInvariant = Name

End Function
```

Full code and documentation in my library at **GitHub**: [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).

**Addendum:**

To create a text formatted as you have specified, you could use something like this:

```vb
Dim SendDate As Date
Dim TextDateInMail As String

' The date value in the mail to send.
SendDate = Date

' The formatted text date in the mail to send.
TextDateInMail = MonthNameInvariant(Month(SendDate)) & Format(SendDate, " dd, yyyy")

' Value of TextDateInMail:
' April 01, 2023
```

Comment: Can I mark an answer as duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798375/4677305 :p-

Comment: I came across your code in another thread as well. I tried it and it didn't do anything. Also, I tried the above code given it is a bit different from the other thread. But, I get an error as soon as I type 'Public Const MaxMonthValue          As Integer = 12'. Error says: Compile Error: Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and Declare statements not allowed as Public members of object modules. Can you tell what is wrong and what to do in this case?

Comment: Include in the two constants (listed above) in the module header.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook: Oh, you searching is better than my memory.

Comment: @Gustav So I successfully created an independent module with the above code. But in my form, how do I call the function within the private sub of the button click event. Under this private sub, I have other codes i.e. SQL queries (which includes an activation date that's eventually included in the email message that the above code needs to be applied), subject, body etc. I am sorry I am asking too many questions. I am a newbie and just trying to learn. I watched many videos, and took online courses on VBA, but they are all introductory and don't necessarily teach advanced VBA coding.

Comment: No problem. See extended answer, please.

Comment: Thank you so much Gustav! You have been a great help. I had to modify it a bit to make it work for my purpose. But, eventually it worked perfectly. :D